# The formidable game of prime

Tags: algebra-precalculus, prime-numbers

Does there exist any set of solution for equation $x^n*(y-u)=y^r-u$, where $x, y,r$ are prime numbers, $(x+1)$ and $(y-u)$ are powers of $2$, $u\in\{1,-1\}$ and $n$ is an integer except $(x,y,r,n,u)=(7,3,3,1,-1), (31,5,3,1,1)$?

Comment: That seems to be a very specific set of conditions...  can you provide any further context of this problem?

Comment: Your second example seems to fail the $y+1=2^k$ test...

Comment: I am afraid I don't have any further context of this problem as this is one of the challenging question posed before us in a mathematics class and I was able to obtain only 2 sets of solution and need only one more set. Thanks!

Comment: I am extremely sorry for the inconvenience caused as it is not y+1 but y-u.

Comment: The context “this was proposed in a math class and I need to come up with three solutions” is very helpful information.

Comment: One thing that may be helpful in finding another solution is that $y^r-u=(y-u)(y^{r-1}+(uy)^{r-2}+y^{r-3}+\dots+uy+1)$, since $r$ is prime.  Obviously if $r=2$ then the RHS is either $(y-1)(y+1)$ or $y^2+1$.

Comment: Thanks for the help abiessu. I am able to generate one more set (3,2,2,1,1)

Comment: You are welcome.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

One further solution is $(x,y,r,n,u)=(3,2,2,1,1)$.  Other solutions may or may not exist, but note that you can almost always cancel the term $y-u$ from both sides by factoring the RHS of your equation.  The one exception to this is when $r=2,u=-1$ in which case the RHS is $y^2+1$ and therefore the LHS becomes $x^n*(y+1)$.  However, in this scenario there are no solutions at all for $x,y,n$ since the LHS will have a minimum $2^k$ factor of $4$ while the RHS will be of the form $2(2q+1)$.

One further group of solutions appears from $x$ in the set of Mersenne primes, $n=1,y=2,u=1$, then $r$ is the prime such that $x=M_r=2^r-1$, the Mersenne number at index $r$.  The definition of $x$ appears to be the same as that of the Mersenne numbers.